# If every maximal ideal of $R$ is finitely generated then is every maximal ideal of $R[x]$ also finitely generated ?

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unity such that every maximal ideal of $R$ is finitely generated (we know such  ring need not be Noetherian). Then is every maximal ideal of $R[x]$  also finitely generated?

Comment: Let $R=\mathbb Z_{(2)}+Y\mathbb Q[[Y]]$. This is a local ring of dimension two, $\mathfrak p=Y\mathbb Q[[Y]]$ is a prime ideal which not finitely generated, and $\mathfrak m=2\mathbb Z_{(2)}+X\mathbb Q[[Y]]$, the maximal ideal, is principal. Let $M=\mathfrak p[X]+(2X-1)$. This is a maximal ideal of $R[X]$ which is not finitely generated.

Comment: I think it's obvious that in order to find a counterexample we need a maximal ideal of $R[X]$ which contracts to a non-maximal ideal.

Comment: The converse holds: if every maximal ideal of $R[X]$ is finitely generated, then every maximal ideal of $R$ is finitely generated.

Comment: @user26857 : how to show that the converse holds ?

Comment: @users If $M$ is a maximal ideal of $R$, then $(M,X)$ is a maximal ideal of $R[X]$, so finitely generated, hence $M$ must be finitely generated in $R$ (look at the independent terms of polynomials)