# On finite generation of extended submodules in formal power series module

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules, maximal-and-prime-ideals, formal-power-series

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unity, and let $M$ be an $R$-module. Then naturally $M[[x]]$ is an $R[[x]]$-module. Moreover, if $M$ is generated over $R$ by $b_1,...,b_n$, then $M[[x]]$ also is generated over $R[[x]]$ by $b_1,...,b_n$.

> Now let $M$ be a finitely generated $R$-module and $P$ be a prime ideal of $R[[x]]$ such that the submodule $(PM)^*:= \{f(0) \in M : f(x)\in PM[[x]] \} $ of $M$ is finitely generated. Then is it true that $PM[[x]]$ also is a finitely generated submodule of $M[[x]]$?

I know the claim to be true for $M=R$ which is a Theorem in Kaplansky's commutative ring theory book. For the question I asked, I can only show that if $x\in P$, then $PM[[x]]$ is finitely generated by $a_1,...,a_n, xb_1,...,xb_n$ over $R[[x]]$, where $a_1,...,a_n$ generate $(PM)^*$ over $R$ and $b_1,...,b_n$ generate $M$ over $R$.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but doesn't the case $M=R$ show that $P$ is finitely generated over $R[[x]]$, say $P=\langle p_1,\dots,p_m\rangle$, and then $PM[[x]]=\langle p_i b_j, i=1,\dots,m, j=1,\dots,n\rangle$?

Comment: @san $P$ is finitely generated when $P^*$ is, that is, for the particular case $M=R$.

Comment: @misao If $M$ is flat then you can mimic the proof from Kaplansky. In this case $Xg(X)\in PM[[X]]$ anx $X\notin P$ implies $g\in PM[[X]]$.

Comment: @misao In general, the property doesn't hold. In a comment under [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2439351/if-every-maximal-ideal-of-r-is-finitely-generated-then-is-every-maximal-ideal#comment5039644_2439351) I gave an example of a valuation domain (denoted by $R$). The prime ideal $P=\mathfrak p[[X]]+(2X-1)$ is not finitely generated. Now consider the $R$-module $M=R/I$, where $I=(Y)$. (Note that $I\subset\mathfrak p$.) We have $(PM[[X]])^*=M$. If $PM[[X]]$ is finitely generated then $P$ is finitely generated, a contradiction.

Comment: @user26857 : for a flat module $M$ , how do you say that $X g(X)\in PM[[X]]$ and $X \notin P$ implies $g(X)\in PM[[X]]$ ?

Comment: @misao Since $M$ is $R$-flat we have that $M[[X]]$ is $R[[X]]$-flat. From $X\notin P$ we get that the multiplication by $X$ is injective on $R[[X]]/$. Now tensor by $M[[X]]$.

Comment: @user26857 : Thanks . Could you please give a reference to the fact that $M$ is $R$ flat implies $M[[x]]$ is $R[[x]]$ flat ?

Comment: @misao Well, this should follow from the base change for flatness and $R[[X]]\otimes_RM\simeq M[[X]]$, but after a second thought I think the isomorphism holds if $M$ is of finite presentation, that is, finitely generated is not enough.